# Partial derivatives.

Tags: functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose

$$f(x+y, x^2 +xy + z^2) = 0.$$

Show that

$$x + y = 2z\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right).$$

Please help I don't know where to start!

Comment: You haven't defined f. What is it?

Comment: The comma indicates that it is a function of (x+y) and (x^2 +xy+z^2) ie it is a function of functions.

Comment: I get that, but what is the function? It is impossible to demonstrate this equivalence without knowing what the function is.

Comment: Something does not add up. You say  "suppose..." and then "where $f$ is..." if you have not forgotten something, then you express  yourself wrongly. Also in what you need to show, are you sure that $f$ is not there?

Comment: Im pretty sure a 1st year Chemistry students maths homework is not impossible, that is exactly what the question asks. Its a past exam question so I'd say its fairly credible.

Comment: "Where f is a function as shown above." suggests that $f$ is defined before "Suppose", maybe in a previous discussion in a textbook?

Comment: Can anyone actually show me some working I'm really stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that 
$$k(x,y)=x+y$$
$$l(x,y,z(x,y))=x^2+xy+z^2$$
Then the function becomes
$$f\bigg(k(x,y),l\big(x,y,z(x,y)\big)\bigg)=0$$
If you take the total differential
$$df=\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\frac{\partial l}{\partial x}\bigg)dx+\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\frac{\partial l}{\partial y}\bigg)dy=0$$
And then
$$\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial x}=2x+y+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial k}{\partial y}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial y}=x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
By replacing these equations into total differenatial
$$df=\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(2x+y+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)\bigg)dx+\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg)dy=0$$
Without loss of generality
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(2x+y+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)=0$$
We can combine both equations such that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(2x+y+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}\bigg(x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)$$
By substracting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}$ and then dividing by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}$ we have
$$2x+y+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
which can be simplified to
$$x+y=2z\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)$$

Answer (score -1):

It seems you assume $z=z(x, y)$. So from $f(x+y, x^2+xy+z^2)=0$, by chain rule, you get
$$
\begin{align}
f_1+f_2(2x+y+2z z_x)&=0\\
f_1+f_2(y+2z z_y)&=0
\end{align}
$$
Taking a subtraction...

Comment: Could you explain your notation.

Comment: @Anon $f_1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, f_1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $z_x=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, z_y=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to that, sorry I'm not to good with chain rules.

Comment: Please can you answer my question :)

Comment: @Anon This is too simple, I cannot help you. Please read your text book.